# Postgresql: wrong Index Scan cost estimation leads to wrong plan

Tags: postgresql, query-performance

The query only involves with one table `act` with definition:

```
┌────────────────┬──────────────┬───────────┐
│     Column     │     Type     │ Modifiers │
├────────────────┼──────────────┼───────────┤
│ loan_id        │ bigint       │ not null  │
│ dt             │ date         │ not null  │
│ dlq_stat       │ character(3) │           │
└────────────────┴──────────────┴───────────┘
Indexes:
    "act_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (loan_id, dt)
```

`act` contains about `20.7M` records and `611K` unique `loan_id`. The idea of the intended query is to find the last `dt` of each `loan_id`, then collect such records together.

### Query 1

```
with maxdt as
(
  select loan_id, max(dt) as maxdt
    from act
   group by loan_id
)
select maxdt.loan_id,
       maxdt.maxdt as lastdt,
       act.dlq_stat
  from maxdt
  join act
    on maxdt.loan_id = act.loan_id
   and maxdt.maxdt = act.dt;
```

with query plan:

```
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                 QUERY PLAN                                                              │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Nested Loop  (cost=527126.77..1105840.68 rows=103725 width=21) (actual time=28608.305..5754855.397 rows=611347 loops=1)                 │
│   CTE maxdt                                                                                                                             │
│     ->  HashAggregate  (cost=526395.38..527126.21 rows=73083 width=12) (actual time=28599.889..29572.679 rows=611347 loops=1)           │
│           Group Key: act.loan_id                                                                                                        │
│           ->  Seq Scan on act  (cost=0.00..422669.92 rows=20745092 width=12) (actual time=10.527..24174.317 rows=20744968 loops=1)      │
│   ->  CTE Scan on maxdt  (cost=0.00..1461.66 rows=73083 width=12) (actual time=28599.893..30635.047 rows=611347 loops=1)                │
│   ->  Index Scan using act_pkey on act act  (cost=0.56..7.87 rows=2 width=21) (actual time=9.347..9.358 rows=1 loops=611347)            │
│         Index Cond: ((loan_id = maxdt.loan_id) AND (dt = maxdt.maxdt))                                                                  │
│ Planning time: 0.275 ms                                                                                                                 │
│ Execution time: 5755033.052 ms                                                                                                          │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

### Query 2

```
with maxdt as
(
  select loan_id, max(dt) as maxdt
    from act
   group by loan_id
   order by loan_id   /* order is forced to take advantage of locality of the index */
)
select maxdt.loan_id,
       maxdt.maxdt as lastdt,
       act.dlq_stat
  from maxdt
  join act
    on maxdt.loan_id = act.loan_id
   and maxdt.maxdt = act.dt;
```

with query plan:

```
┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                   QUERY PLAN                                                            │
├─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Nested Loop  (cost=533213.58..1111927.48 rows=103725 width=21) (actual time=19036.526..57610.487 rows=611347 loops=1)                   │
│   CTE maxdt                                                                                                                             │
│     ->  Sort  (cost=533030.31..533213.02 rows=73083 width=12) (actual time=19036.484..19101.752 rows=611347 loops=1)                    │
│           Sort Key: act.loan_id                                                                                                         │
│           Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 53233kB                                                                                       │
│           ->  HashAggregate  (cost=526395.38..527126.21 rows=73083 width=12) (actual time=18699.754..18857.285 rows=611347 loops=1)     │
│                 Group Key: act.loan_id                                                                                                  │
│                 ->  Seq Scan on act  (cost=0.00..422669.92 rows=20745092 width=12) (actual time=0.005..14234.374 rows=20744968 loops=1) │
│   ->  CTE Scan on maxdt  (cost=0.00..1461.66 rows=73083 width=12) (actual time=19036.489..19351.742 rows=611347 loops=1)                │
│   ->  Index Scan using act_pkey on act act  (cost=0.56..7.87 rows=2 width=21) (actual time=0.061..0.061 rows=1 loops=611347)            │
│         Index Cond: ((loan_id = maxdt.loan_id) AND (dt = maxdt.maxdt))                                                                  │
│ Planning time: 0.217 ms                                                                                                                 │
│ Execution time: 57662.761 ms                                                                                                            │
└─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

### Query 3

As suggested by @Laurenz, the Query 3 employs the Hash Anti Join for the job.

```
explain analyze
select loan_id, dt, dlq_stat
  from act
 where not exists (
         select NULL
           from act as a
          where a.loan_id = act.loan_id
            and a.dt > act.dt
       );
```

with query plan:

```
┌──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│                                                                QUERY PLAN                                                        │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ Hash Anti Join  (cost=783278.57..2036132.40 rows=13830061 width=21) (actual time=88983.113..295036.106 rows=611347 loops=1)      │
│   Hash Cond: (act.loan_id = a.loan_id)                                                                                           │
│   Join Filter: (a.dt > act.dt)                                                                                                   │
│   Rows Removed by Join Filter: 20744968                                                                                          │
│   ->  Seq Scan on act  (cost=0.00..422669.92 rows=20745092 width=21) (actual time=0.004..84807.803 rows=20744968 loops=1)        │
│   ->  Hash  (cost=422669.92..422669.92 rows=20745092 width=12) (actual time=88937.978..88937.978 rows=20744968 loops=1)          │
│         Buckets: 4194304  Batches: 16  Memory Usage: 89089kB                                                                     │
│         ->  Seq Scan on act a  (cost=0.00..422669.92 rows=20745092 width=12) (actual time=0.007..85665.452 rows=20744968 loops=1)│
│ Planning time: 129.782 ms                                                                                                        │
│ Execution time: 295058.407 ms                                                                                                    │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

### Observations and Question

Nested loop with index scan are chosen for both queries. Yet the first query is super slow: if the data is cold, it might run well over 1 hour. While the second query was efficient by taking advantage of the index locality with a forced order on `loan_id`. It can usually finish within 1 minute.

The major issue per my observation the cost of index scan is drastically underestimated for the first query... a major cause of many postgresql performance problems. When the drive table `maxdt` is not ordered, the cost of index scan is not up to `seq_page_cost` but `random_page_cost`.

Query 3 is a reasonable approach too, yet its performance is slightly worse than Query 2. I don't know how to compare *Hash Anti Join* with *Hash Join*, given the join conditions are also different.

In closing, here are two questions:

1. Whether can we build such logic into the postgresql query builder? Understand it is a long shot.
2. Whether is there a nice way to force the above query to use `Hash Join`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When you say that the cost of the index scan is underestimated, are you referring to `cost=0.56..7.87`? This is the cost of a single index scan, the total estimated cost is that value times the estimated loop count `73083`.
That latter value is actually low by a factor 8.4 which *might* be improved by a higher `default_statistics_target` setting.

I suggest that you write the query like this:

```
SELECT loan_id, dt, dlq_stat
FROM act
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT NULL
   FROM act a
   WHERE a.loan_id = act.loan_id AND a.dt > act.dt
);
```

That should lead to a query plan like

```
Hash Anti Join
  Hash Cond: (act.loan_id = a.loan_id)
  Join Filter: (a.dt > act.dt)
  ->  Seq Scan on act
  ->  Hash
        ->  Seq Scan on act a
```

Comment: Yes, I was referring to `cost=0.56..7.87` for the first query when saying that the cost of index scan is underestimated. The usual index scan is assumed to be a sequential scan: while it does not hold if `maxdt` is not ordered. The cost is off by a factor of close to `100` based on this example. Thanks for pointing out the estimated loop count `73083` is too low. I noticed it too. It is treated as second priority for now since it would affect cost estimation for all possible plans.

Will try out the query you suggested and report back. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure, but maybe a multicolumn index on `(loan_id, dt)` would help with my query. If not, then maybe you should stick with your best alternative.

Comment: Laurenz, thanks for the suggestion. I tried the query, and it is a good one. Yet its performance is worse than Query 2 -- which is the winner so far. Please see the updated question. (for edit comment)

Answer (score 1):

You could try the Postgres-specific [`DISTINCT ON` clause.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (loan_id) loan_id, dt AS lastdt, dlq_stat
FROM act
ORDER BY loan_id, dt DESC;
```

I don't know whether PostgreSQL is smart enough to use the index for that query. Redoing the index as `(loan_id, dt DESC)` instead of a plain `(loan_id, dt)` may help.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `DISTINCT ON`. It is a nice plan:  the execution is implemented on sorting rather than using index scan, and the running time is comparable to *Query 2* -- or slightly better. The point is that a good plan cannot use index scan blindly, or it would fail.

Redo the index as `(loan_id, dt DESC)` would have no impact IMHO. Actually, the `DISTINCT ON` would not use the index at all.

Comment: Re: 'would have no impact'; Postgres can use compound indices for some queries that rely on sorting, but the index asc/desc must match the ones used in the sort clause. `ORDER BY loan_id DESC, dt DESC` ought to work too. Of course, it is likely that Postgres estimates that too many records are to be returned for an index scan to be worth it.

Comment: I see your point. It is an interesting argument. Now `DISTINCT ON` works great since the current plan does not use index at all. I will do a test with the index re-defined as `(loan_id, dt DESC)`, and see how it goes. Will report back.